# Updating all textboxes on a form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a userform with roughly 30 textboxes.

I have an on_change where the textboxes update using DSums and Dcounts - The problem is it appears not all textboxes are updating.

Is there an alternative way to requey, or refresh boxes?

Example Code:

```
CashE = DSum("[Total Amount]", "[tbl_Cash_Yesterday]", "[Processed By] = '" & Text285 & "' and [Field19] = 'Evening'") - DSum("[Aged Relief]", "[tbl_Cash_Yesterday]", "[Processed By] = '" & Text285 & "' and [Field19] = 'Evening'")
```

Comment: Please provide an example of code you use in OnChange event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the code to my original question

Comment: Please show your full code. It is unclear how/when this line is called. Does each textbox have their own Change event?

Comment: Could you not give the form a `RecordSource` and then the textbox a `Control Source` and have it updated from a query?  Also is generally good practice to rename your controls - `Text285` means nothing while `txtSurname` gives a good indication as to what the control holds (same with fields).

Answer (score 0):

You might try saving the data after updates. Add

```
Me.Dirty = false
```

and see if that doesn't refresh everything from the saved data.